# What is "rsh" and how to disable it?

Tags: rhel, services, rsh

I've never heard of the word `rsh` before, but I received a checklist from a security advisor that we have to "disable `rsh`".

Can someone please tell me what `rsh` and how to disable it, please?

We are using RHEL 5.5 and 5.6.

Comment: Had a look at [what Wikipedia proposes "Rsh" might be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsh)? [Remote Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_shell) sounds like something a security pro might advise you to disable... I don't know RHEL, but maybe editing `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh` is a solution (look for `disable`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rsh is remote shell and it is unencrypted, that's why you should disable it.

I don't know which OS you are talking about, but for RHEL (like sr_ already stated) edit `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh` and set `disable = yes`.

After that restart `xinetd` and you're done.

Though I think, rsh should be disabled by default. Instead of rsh use ssh.

For more information on rsh read the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rsh).

Comment: sorry i didnt mention the Operating System. Now i have updated the Question and I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To disable rsh access (on RHEL 5.11 servers) I had to do the following:

Edit `/etc/xinetd.d/rlogin`, and set `disable = yes`

And after that restart `xinetd`.

Comment: How does this differ from the 4 year old accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove rsh-server rpm package

```
# rpm -qa --last | grep -i ^rsh
# yum remove rsh-server -y 
# yum remove rsh-client -y
# yum remove rsh -y
```